# Printing labels along with equation numbers

Tags: cross-referencing, amsmath

Working with documents with huge amount of equations it becomes cumbersome to go back and remind yourself what you labeled a certain equation to (I try to name them in a smart way, but there are too many).

Is there a convenient way to have equations print the label along with the tag/number, so that I can easily check the label in the compiled document?

Something like this would be perfect:

```
x = y               (14.1) eq:my_label
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use the [`showkeys` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/showkeys) (it's compatible with [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\usepackage{showkeys}% http://ctan.org/pkg/showkeys
\begin{document}
\section{A section} \label{sec:label}
It is clear that
\begin{equation}
   a = b \label{eq:my_label}
\end{equation}
so, from~\eqref{eq:my_label} in Section~\ref{sec:label}, we see that\ldots
\end{document}​
```

It highlights the use of `\label`, `\ref`, `\pageref`, `\cite` and `\bibitem` within your document by means of an "overlay" so as to not affect the typesetting of the document.

Answer (score 27):

The [`refcheck`](http://ctan.org/pkg/refcheck) package does something like that. Questionmarks around the label indicate that you haven't referred to that equation yet. (You have to compile twice for this check to work.)

[image: sample output with refcheck and a couple of equations]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{refcheck}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}
\kant[1]
\begin{equation}\label{eq:1}
a = b
\end{equation}
\kant[2]
\begin{gather}
a = b \label{eq:2}\\
c = d \label{eq:3}
\end{gather}

See \eqref{eq:1}.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11):

[`showkeys`](http://ctan.org/pkg/showkeys) package does exactly this.

Answer (score 7):

Another package providing similar functionality is `showlabels`

Answer (score 2):

All three packages suggested above:

- showlabels
- showkeys
- refcheck

worked for me.
Yet, I had to increase the right margin such that the printed labels are not cut off
`\usepackage[a4paper,left=1cm,right=4cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm]{geometry}`.

Comment: This does have the desired result of showing the full label, but be aware that it will change the line breaking, so the original page geometry should be restored before trying to produce the final version of your document.  (On the other hand, since breaking wide display math to fit is often a problem, working with a narrower line width may be an advantage.)