# LaTeX Printing reference identifier along side reference number

Tags: equations, cross-referencing

I am wondering if it is possible to turn on (or create) a feature that would cause all reference numbers to be printed with the variable name that defines that reference? For instance:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}![enter image description here][2]   
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
Some Description here...  \\
see equation (\ref{equ:linear} \textcolor{red}{equ:linear})

\begin{align}
    y &= mx + c \label{equ:linear} \\
    y &= ax^2 + bx + c \label{equ:Quadratic}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The reason for this is that during compilation of a big document with many many referenes, I often forget what a reference was called and have to go digging back through the document. My fear is that I will make a mistake (ie distinguishing between `\ref{equ:Gda2p}` and `\ref{equ:Gda2r}`). Hence, I could look at the semi completed pdf document which is very easy to navigate and already open beside me and see the reference name printed in the pdf.

Of course, I would want to turn this feature off before my final publish to remove all excess reference information

Ive had a bit of a look for something like this on Google but was not successful

Comment: `\usepackage{showkeys}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45634/printing-labels-along-with-equation-numbers/

Answer (score 1):

```
\usepackage{showkeys}
```

`showkeys` is in the standard tools distribution to support this feature.