# Good practice for \label{}, \ref{} and \pager{}?

Tags: cross-referencing

I often give rather arbitrary `\label{name}`, and it can be a challenge to recall things and write `\ref{name}`, or `\pageref{name}`.

Are there recommended practices, which may be helpful. Literature suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Usually I do `\label{tab:foo}` or `\label{eq:foo}` and so on... `fig:`, `sec:` etc

Comment: @Sigur tabular, equation, figure, section? foo?

Comment: I usually use hierarchical label names similar to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228022/label-naming-strategy (but I use `.` instead of `:`) and usual prefixes like shown by Sigur above. But I think that's more or less a matter of personal taste and document-dependent requirements.

Comment: There's no point in `\label`ing a `tabular` environment, as no counter is associated with it. @Sigur has already provided a hint for how to approach the `\label`ing of `equation` and `table` objects. This convention can be extended in a very naturally to `figure` and `section` objects. The key is that these objects need to be associated with a number that `\label` can latch on to. I have no idea what `foo` could stand for. E.g., is it an object that is numbered in some systematic way? If it's not, there's again no point in affixing a `\label` directive to begin with.

Comment: `foo` is a non meaning word used when we want to say that it should be replace by anything. `foo, faa, bla` and others....