# Label text shows up beside equation number when using align environment?

Tags: math-mode, equations, align, mathtools

When I put a label in an align environment it lets me reference the corresponding equation properly, but in it also puts the text in this label beside the equation number. Why is it doing this, and how I can get rid of the label text?

```
\begin{align}
\label{eq1}(\Delta + 1) u(x) &= \frac{1}{\lambda} n(x) u(x) \quad \quad \text{in} \ D, \\
\label{eq2}(\Delta + 1) u(x) &= 0 \quad \quad \text{in} \ \mathbb{R}^2\backslash D, \\
\shortintertext{\centering{$u$ satisfies the Sommerfeld radiation condition.}}
\end{align}
```

[image]
How do I get rid of the {eq1} and {eq2} text?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! We need to see an MWE. A minimal but compilable example. This is not the normal behavior so we have to take a look on what you actually do.

Comment: [Remove labels from showing up in final document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/285425)